# Using different version of hadoop client library with apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to run two or more jobs in parallel. All jobs write append data using same output path, problem is that first job that finishes does cleanup and erases _temporary folder which causes other jobs to throw exception.

With hadoop-client 3 there is a configuration flag to disable auto cleanup of this folder **mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup.skipped**.

I was able to exclude dependencies from spark-core and add new hadoop-client using maven. This run fine for master=local but I'm not convinced it is correct.

My questions are

- Is it possible to use different hadoop-client library with apache spark (e.g. hadoop-client version 3 with apache spark 2.3) and what is the correct approach?
- Is there better way to run multiple jobs in parallel writing under same path?

Comment: Is there a watch button in SO, I am interested in keeping an eye on this

Comment: If you shade those libraries into your Spark application, and find/set the `user classpath first` configuration setting to true, then it _might work_.